# Backing up with dd

Tags: 12.04, backup, dd

I follow the instruction in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54869/clonezilla-like-app-for-the-desktop/54883?noredirect=1#comment466007_54883), using the command

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 | gzip > disk.img.gz
```

but the imaging does not seem to stop. Is it because the disk.img is being put (as default) in my Home folder, which is on the same /dev/sda1 partition that I am imaging? (The size of /dev/sda1 is 24GB, but the img file is 32 GB and counting)

```
 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   484491263   242244608   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       484493310   488396799     1951745    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       484493312   488396799     1951744   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

If so, given my partition scheme, to solution is to `cd` to an external hard drive then use the above command?

EDIT: Added the output of `lsblk`

```
 NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
 sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
 ├─sda1   8:1    0   231G  0 part /
 ├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
 └─sda5   8:5    0   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Comment: Please run the `lsblk` command and edit your post with the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> /dev/sda1   *        2048   484491263   242244608   83  Linux
> ```

1 block is 512 bytes. 242244608 blocks is 115.5 GiB, not 24 as you mentioned. The `dd` command (refered by you as "imaging") keeps writing data to the same partition that you are cloning. This does *not* cause any loops, but it may yield a corrupt filesystem image (`disk.img.gz`).

What you *should* do is:

1. Reboot to a Live CD.
2. Ensure that your source partition is not mounted.
3. Mount a different target partition (e.g. your external hard disk).
4. Use `dd` to write the image to your second partition.

Even better, if you do not need to have an identical filesystem copy, just use `rsync` to copy your files and metadata (permissions). For this you need your backup target to have the same filesystem type (ext4) such that permissions and ACLs are preserved. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_System_Backup_with_rsync for details on using `rsync`.

Comment: Yes, the total size of sda1 is 115 GB, but the used space is 24 GB. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, you are creating an infinite loop by making a backup of the disk the backup is written to!

What you need to do is write the image to a other device; attach an external USB or SATA hard drive, mount it, and run `dd if=/dev/sda1 | gzip > /<mountpoint>/disk.img.gz`

You may also use [dd, gzip and ssh](http://blog.esmnetworks.com/infrastructure/drive-backup-over-ssh-compressed-with-gzip/) to dump the disk to a machine on your LAN.

Comment: There is no infinite loop, the maximum size of the image is the available space of the Home partition.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was looking at the numbers, not the partition-size. 32GB > 24GB, hence the loop answer.